# Assign multiple objects one to a frame inside one track of a geometry cache?

Tags: python, alembic

So, i'm pretty new to this, so please excuse me if this is wrong place, or there is a better way to do what i am doing.

Overview: Lets say I have 20 objects that together make up my fire animation (lets assume fire1,fire2,etc).  My end goal is to export out a geometry cache containing one track with one object in each frame of the track (ie... fire1 is in frame 1 of track, fire2 is in frame 2 of track, so on and so forth).

Currently I have this kind of working by placing all my objects in blender, selecting them in the order I want, and then running this script:

```
import bpy
import random

#define how long the smoke clouds stay for 
duration = 1

def allOffAt(objs,index):
    for cube in objs:
        cube.hide_viewport = True
        cube.hide_render = True
        cube.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_viewport", index=-1, frame=index)
        cube.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_render", index=-1, frame=index)    

selected_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects
total_frames = len(selected_objects) 
bpy.context.scene.frame_start = 1
bpy.context.scene.frame_end = total_frames
bpy.context.scene.frame_current = bpy.context.scene.frame_start 

allOffAt(selected_objects,0)


frame_nums = []
for x in range(bpy.context.scene.frame_start,bpy.context.scene.frame_end +1):
    frame_nums.append(x)
#random.shuffle(frame_nums)

frm_cnt = 0
for cube in selected_objects:
    #unhide it
    cube.hide_viewport = False
    cube.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_viewport", index=-1, frame=frame_nums[frm_cnt])
    cube.hide_render = False
    cube.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_render", index=-1, frame=frame_nums[frm_cnt])
    cube.hide_viewport = True
    cube.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_viewport", index=-1, frame=frame_nums[frm_cnt]+duration)
    cube.hide_render = True
    cube.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_render", index=-1, frame=frame_nums[frm_cnt]+duration)
    frm_cnt += 1
```

I then export this as a alembic file via blender export, and I can drop it in unreal engine and it mostly works.  Except that instead of being 20 objects in 1 track of the geometry cache.  There is 20 different tracks one for each object.  This mostly work because UE compresses it for me during import.  But my goal is to actually have, lets say 3 tracks in the geometry cache (fire start sequence, fire going sequence, fire ending sequence). So that I can have the actions happen at the end of different parts of the track  So i'd like to somehow have my code also set what track of the geometry cache the items are stored in...

Is this possible?  Is there a better way to go about getting 1 object per frame then using renderability and visibility?

Thanks for any insight... As I said, total noob here, so even if its just to point me in a direction, I appreciate it.

Comment: Does each frame (mesh) in your animation have the same number of vertices?  If so, you could condense them into a single mesh using Shape Keys, one shape key for each frame. Then you can animate the % weight of each shape key.